# Unable to sign in using UserName

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET MVC app template and I'm changing things based on my needs. When I want ti login a registered user I want to login by `userName`. I register via e-mail and then change e-mail value which is stored under `userName` to some username.

When I try to login I get Login attempt failed.

Using debugger I found out the source of the problem.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }


            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
```

So the part wiht `!ModelState.IsValid` works and tahts fine.

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

This line of code returns `Failure` and my Login attemp is failed.

I disabled `RequireUniqueEmail` from `SignInManager` but that didnt help. I think the problem is that somwhere inside Microsofts classes `E-mail` is still required and Im not providing it therfore my login fails.

I altered the View and `LoginViewModel` with new property `UserName` and `AspNetUsers` db table has field called `UserName` and is updated with my new values.

Answer (score 1):

Change your view model like:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

In your login view like:

```
@*your fields or code*@
               <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
@*your fields or code*@
```

In Login Action Change like:

```
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

I think you no need to do else. ( tested using default ASP MVC5 code )

Comment: I have the exact same code which I figured should work but for some reason this won't work for me.

Comment: @ Ashiquzzaman yes I did but how is reverting going to help when I wanto to use the `UserName ` not `Email `?

Comment: When I create user I change his `UserName ` to something random with `ActionResult Edit` in my other `Controller`. Then  `UserName != Email`.
Could that be the problem?

Comment: @brika28 yes. you no need to do anything except my answer. If you really need to set the filed `UserName ` in your database. then do like -- `var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName , Email = model.Email }; ` and insert or update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211376/discussion-between-brika28-and-ashiquzzaman).

Answer (score 0):

You must try with this

```
 public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
// Your Code
var result = SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false).Result;
// Your Code
}
```

I think it should work.

- Krunal Dave

Comment: I will get back to you when I try it. What does `Result` do?

Comment: It execute  this statement and also execute below statement.

Comment: The result with that line changed is the same. I still get Invalid login attempt.